# Alternative of findFragmentById for getting a reference of already open fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments

Im trying to tell a fragment to change a certain view's visibility from the activity, but I dont know how to get a reference to that fragment.

What I found is

```
 findFragmentById(R.id.asdasd)
```

But my fragment is not inflated from an XML layout so it doesnt have such an ID (I guess?)

So how can I reference this fragment in another way?

Here is how I add the fragment from the activity:

```
public void addFragment(Fragment fragment) {
    String fragmentClassName = ((Object) fragment).getClass().getSimpleName();
    FragmentTransaction t = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    t.replace(R.id.fragment_container, fragment, fragmentClassName);
    t.addToBackStack(fragmentClassName);
    t.commit();
```

Comment: can you post the code where you show your fragment using FragmentTrasaction

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you already set the **tag** in your fragment you can use it to find the fragment by its tag using the Fragment Manager.

**sample:**

```
 String fragmentClassName = The_Class_Name_Of_Fragment.getClass().getSimpleName();
 YourFragment fragment = getFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(fragmentClassName);
```

Comment: this way?

  String fragmentClassName = ((GiraffeFragment) fragment).getClass().getSimpleName();
  GiraffeFragmentfragment = (GiraffeFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(fragmentClassName);

Comment: @J.K. remove the `((GiraffeFragment) fragment)` just put `GiraffeFragment.getClass().getSimpleName(); `

Comment: I get GiraffeFragment.getClass redunderlined and the following error message Cannot make a static reference to the non-static method getClass() from the type Object

Comment: @J.K. sorry it supposed to be `GiraffeFragment.class.getSimpleName();` because you are not getting it from the object but staticly

Comment: hmm it returns null :(

Comment: @J.K. Make sure that the fragment is still alive and set the tag name the same way you get the fragment

Answer (score -2):

You should call `findFragmentById(R.id.fragment_container)` to reference your `Fragment`.

Comment: but I have several fragments in the backstack, how will it know which one is that I want to reference exactly

Comment: By calling replace() you're removing the old fragment from the container and adding a new one; findFragmentById() will return that new fragment. Back stack has nothing to do with it, it's just a means to reverse transactions automatically.

Comment: @Egor findFragmentById search the back stack.